# What are possible causes for differing behaviors in jsFiddle and in local context

Tags: jsfiddle

Upon invsetigating 'mu is too short's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206985/what-can-make-jquerys-unbind-function-not-work-as-expected), I noticed that I get different behaviour in jsFiddle than in my local context for the exact same script. Any clues as to why that is?

Note:
I am not getting any javascript errors in Firefox's error console in the local context.

**UPDATE**:
I tried grabbing the HTML from [fiddle.jshell.net/ambiguous/ZEx6M/1/show/light](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ambiguous/ZEx6M/1/show/light) to a local file and loading that local file in Chromium browser and I got the following errors in the javascript console:

- `GET file:///css/normalize.css undefined (undefined)               /css/normalize.css`
- `GET file:///css/result-light.css undefined (undefined)            /css/result-light.css`
- `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/empty  jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2.js:-1`
- `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain jquery.viewport.js:-1`

I can get rid of these javascript errors by downloading the files and modifying the `<script>` tags, but it doesn't solve the problem. The page still scrolls down to the very bottom. Also these errors appear even in the working (jsFiddle) version.

I also tried the same process in Konqueror. Result: the script does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @mu is too short : Yes, I just tried it and I get the same result (The page calls makeVisibleWhatMust repeatedly until I've scrolled 'till the end)

Comment: Nope, no errors in Firefox. In Konqueror, it seems as though the script does nothing at all. I checked that javascript was enabled, so that's not the problem. Also I can't find any error console in Konqueror, where should I look for errors?

Comment: I didn't think I had Chrome, but I do! Now I'm getting errors! I'll edit them into my original question.

Comment: @mu is too short : That solved the errors, but the page still scrolls down to the very bottom.

Comment: Scrolling in any direction triggers the "scroll to the bottom" for me

Comment: I think that the scrolling up problem could be an error in my logic. Try with different font-sizes (using Ctrl + and Ctrl -) Is scrolling up still a problem with very small font-sizes?

Comment: Thanks for testing.. Anyways, I'm not getting any answers... Even with a bounty! So maybe there's something wrong with my question? What do you think?

Comment: @mu is too short : Success! Copying /css/normalize.css locally made it work! More precisely, the `table { border-collapse:collapse; }` instruction seems necessary for the script to work. Any clues as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use separate files for CSS and javascript.  Just bring everything into HTML file (using inline javascript and inline CSS) and you should be OK.

Or, run a web server locally to serve the javascript file (with the correct MIME type) and use relative paths to CSS.

Comment: Yes, as you can see by the comments of my original question, the difference was due to some CSS added by jsFiddle which I did not have in my local context.